# How to prevent dropdown menu to close when calling onclick with js on another button

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, click, focus

i have a simple drop down menu and a button that submits an ajax form in a page and a js function calls `onclick` function of that button on a loop with some delay (every 10 sec `onclick` method of that button calls and therefore some form get submitted and refreshes).
now the problem is every time that button get clicked through js code dropdown menu closes automatically.
i suspect that calling onclick of that button steal the focus of dropdown menu and because of that each time js code calls it menu closes.
so, how can i prevent such a behavior when onclick of button get called? or is there any better way is to submit a ajax form on a loop with delay?

**UPDATE**
Code is a part of big project but for better understanding you can consider something like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
   <span class="caret"></span></button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

<form action="/navigationbar/_submitpush" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#pushwindow" id="form3" method="post">
    <button id="pushsubmitButton" type="submit" style="display:none">realSubmitButton</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkingPush() {
            //Doing something
            setTimeout(goingToLoop, 5000);
        }
        function goingToLoop() {
            document.getElementById('pushsubmitButton').click();
        }
        checkingPush();
    </script>
</form>
</div>
```

Every 5 sec `goingToLoop` calls and that call `onclick` function of `pushsubmitButton` button and drop down menu closes

AND you can simulate that with dev console of browser (open drop down menu, execute `document.getElementById('pushsubmitButton').click()` in console and menu closes even if button placed outside of form and do nothing)

Comment: impossible to really tell without seeing code with the issue. We can make guesses, but it is just guesses.

Comment: @epascarello i added some code sample

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that bootstraps dropdown is build using css and stays open by `:focus`. Simulating a click on an other element also sets the `:focus` to the other element.

You could change your dropdown to a JavaScript-solution or simulating a click on the dropdown-button after your click on your pushsubmitButton.